# How to remove warning about storing unencrypted password after committing file in svn

Tags: linux, svn, unix

Every time I commit a file in svn I get the following message:

> ATTENTION!  Your password for authentication realm:
>
> http://domainname.com:80 “domainname.com”
>
> can only be stored to disk unencrypted!  You are advised to configure
>   your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if
>   possible.  See the documentation for details.
>   You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value
>   of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in '/root/.subversion/servers'.
>
> ---
>
> Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? no

I don't want this authentication; how can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: You're running as root? bad plan my friend.

Answer (score 45):

You are not storing the password in Subversion because you answered *no* to the question whether or not you want to store this password.

I take it you want to eliminate this <strike>error</strike> *warning* message entirely. There are two ways to handle that:

- **The easy, but hard way**: You can specify `svn  --no-auth-cache` each and every time you a Subversion command. It's easy to do since it requires no real action on your part. It's hard because you have to do this almost every time you use a Subversion command (especially one that touches the repository like `checkout` and `commit`).
- **The hard, but easy way**: You can modify your user's Subversion configuration not to ask if you want to store this information. (BTW, why are you running as *root*? You like living life on the edge? Better off running as a user and configure `sudo` to allow you to do the root stuff you need. That way, you can track who's doing what, and you don't do something that could accidentally bring the server down. In fact, many Unix/Linux systems by default no longer allow a user to sign in as `root`. You have to do `sudo`). This is hard because you have to do something, but easy because once you do it, you don't have to do anything again.

You have the name of the file that you need to edit (`/root/.subversion/servers`). Look for the `[global]` section and look for the line `# store-passwords = no` and remove the `#` from the beginning of the line. You can also do the same for the `# store-plaintext-passwords = no` line and the `# store-auth-cred = no` line. While, you're at it, you can also delete the files under the `auth` directory which is where Subversion stores its credentials. This will completely eliminate already stored passwords. More information can be found in the on line [Red Bean Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers).

Now, when you do a Subversion command that touches the repository, it'll ask you for a user name and password and won't ask if you want to store them.

Comment: Do we have to restart anything after making these changes, seems like the changes did not take effect

Comment: Shouldn't have to do a restart. Subversion looks at the user's configuration file with each `svn` command.

Comment: FYI for the less experienced Linux users: To make the changes outlined by David W. for a non-root user, the servers file to edit may be in /home/USERNAME/.subversion/

Comment: +1 The first option has been useful for me where I have some scripts that export from SVN as a CI user but do not want those (limited) credentials to overwrite my own.

Answer (score 10):

You copied the full warning message here. Reading it instead of just copy/pasting it would answer your question:

> you can avoid future appearances of
>   this warning by setting the value of
>   the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option
>   to either 'yes' or 'no' in
>   '/root/.subversion/servers'.

Comment: Its fine though, it helps to learn of the actual perspective in the why and how and also any alternate ways that David W suggested

Comment: The only thing I would add is to make sure the value is added to the `[global]` section of the file

Answer (score 5):

The subversion client is only asking for authentication because the server requires it. To get rid of the authentication requirement, you'll have to change the server's configuration (e.g., in Apache, get rid of `AuthType`, `AuthName`, and `AuthUserFile`). You can use other authentication methods which do not require passwords (for example, client certificates).

If you just want to get rid of the save password unencrypted prompt, you can set `store-plaintext-passwords=off` (by editing `~/.subversion/config`) or you can make encrypted passwords work by getting (on Unices) the GNOME keyring or KDE wallet running. On Windows, SVN should automatically use built-in NTFS encryption; on Mac OS X, the Keyring. See the [Client Credentials section of the SVN Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds) for further details.

You could also encrypt your home directory on Unix. Then the credentials would be encrypted as well (but of course available to any program running as you or root while you're logged in, similar to the NTFS encryption).

If you don't want SVN to store passwords at all, encrypted or not, set `store-passwords=no` in the SVN config file.