# How to bypass or overcome the authentication realm at execution of SVN command?

Tags: svn

Whenever I execute svn command then command prompt is asking authentication realm.How to overcome this?

ATTENTION!  Your password for authentication realm:

https://server.domain.name.in:8443 VisualSVN Server

can only be stored to disk unencrypted!  You are advised to configure
your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if
possible.  See the documentation for details.

You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value
of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in

### 'C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming/Subversion/servers'.

Store password unencrypted (yes/no)?

Comment: I think answer is there in your question only.

Comment: Actually Im running svn command through pragmatically.So, that time   not able to get result because of  this authentication realm.How to overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove warning about storing unencrypted password after commiting file in svn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606782/how-to-remove-warning-about-storing-unencrypted-password-after-commiting-file-in)

Comment: Ya..I referred that above post but that is giving the expected result at running the svn command in command prompt manually.when Im running same command through java program then it is not returning any result.I guess some authentication issue.How to fix this??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a certificate issue,just I added some additional keywords to my svn command line to overcome this issue.

keywords :

--no-auth-cache  --non-interactive   --trust-server-cert

Now all svn commands are executing fine through java(tomcat server).